# I need to select the first non-hidden/visible child element excluding records with a specific class only using css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In the below example, I want to change the text color of the first child that is visible.

Here `<div>` with the class of `HideWidget` should be excluded; so, I *want* to see "two," "four" and "eight" to be colored red.

I have tried below css and its showing only "four":

```css
.parent .child .field:not(.HideWidget):first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    <div class='field HideWidget'>One</div>
    <div class='field'>Two</div>
    <div class='field'>Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    <div class='field'>Four</div>
    <div class='field'>Five</div>
    <div class='field'>Six</div>
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    <div class='field HideWidget'>Seven</div>
    <div class='field'>Eight</div>
    <div class='field'>Nine</div>
  </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywhmgL49/)

Comment: You can not use `:first-child` like this. That selector is based on DOM position only, and you can not combine it with other "limiting" selectors. The first `.field` child of your first `.child` div will always be the one containing the text "One", no matter what.

Comment: While there are ways of making this specific example work (as in [@Karthik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73249701/82548)) this can't be generalised since there's no way to determine - in CSS - (as yet) whether there would be a subsequent "hidden" element-child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`

```css
.parent .child .field:not(.HideWidget):first-child,
.parent .child .field.HideWidget+.field {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    <div class='field HideWidget'>One</div>
    <div class='field'>Two</div>
    <div class='field'>Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    <div class='field'>Four</div>
    <div class='field'>Five</div>
    <div class='field'>Six</div>
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    <div class='field HideWidget'>Seven</div>
    <div class='field'>Eight</div>
    <div class='field'>Nine</div>
  </div>
```

Should help you with red color on Two, Four and Eight